# Using special abilities?

Tags: monaco

The special abilities of the Locksmith, Cleaner, and Pickpocket are fairly straightforward and easy to use. Locksmith simply gains faster picking speed and the Cleaner just knocks out any unsuspecting enemy he runs into. The special abilities of the Gentleman and the Redhead seem a bit more mysterious.

How do I disguise as a Gentleman and when his disguise drops, how does he re-disguise? As for the Redhead, how do I "charm" the enemies and what does this do exactly?

Comment: The Genlteman appears to automatically apply a disguise when you 'hide'.  So far the only way I've found to 'hide' is by hiding inside a bush, although entering an air duct might work as well.  I don't know enough about how the ability works yet to answer, though.

Comment: I've noticed that if you aren't actively being watched, the Gentleman will re-disguise. Still have no clue about the Redhead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Gentlemen, when he's exposed to guard/civilian sight, the disguise (white circle when exposed to enemy) will starting to worn out, when the white circle disappear completely, guards will start chasing you. When he's not exposed to enemy sight (dark circle when not exposed to enemies), he'll re-disguise automatically.

As for the Redhead, if an angry guard is pursuing your buddy, Redhead will cool him down by "touching" or stay on his sight, the guard will start following her. This effect will last as long as she keeps staying on his sight. However, her ability only works on 1 enemy at a time. You can check if her ability is ready to use by checking at the orange heart over her head

Comment: Is the cooldown per enemy or can she only do it once and then there's a cooldown?

Comment: I've noticed that, sometimes, the guard follows the Redhead around. Does this have any other gameplay effect and would the charmed guard still notice other players?

Comment: @Yawus  No, the charmed guard won't notice other players

Comment: @Alex My apology for giving wrong information about Redhead. I've corrected those information in the answer. She can use the ability as many times as you want, but only one guard at a time. When the charmed guard loses his sight on her, he will turn back to normal and she'll be able to use her ability again

Comment: @Tobi: maybe you can enrich your answer by explaining how the gentleman can lose his disguise

Comment: @BlueTrin I've updated some information for gentlemen. Hope you will find them useful

Comment: I believe charmed guards will also unlock doors for her.